# Prove that minimum value of $f_n(x)=x^{2n}+x^{2n-1}+\dots+x+1$ converges and find its limit

Tags: real-analysis

For each natural number $n$, Assume that $f_n$ is a function defined as below :

$f_n(x)=x^{2n}+x^{2n-1}+\dots+x+1$

And $m_n$ is the minimum of this function on the interval $[-1,0]$.

Prove that the sequence $\{m_n\}$ converges and find its limit.

Note : I don't get it ... Why should $\{m_n\}$ even converge ??  I have no idea how to prove ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $f_n(0)=f_n(-1)=1$ we see that $m_n\le1$ for all $n$. We also have that
$$
f_n(x)=\frac{x^{2n+1}-1}{x-1}\ge\frac{1-x^{2n+1}}{2}\implies m_n\ge\frac12.
$$

$$
f_{n+1}(x)=x^{2n+2}+x^{2n+1}+f_n(x)\le f_n(x)\quad\forall x\in[-1,0].
$$
It follows that $m_n>m_{n+1}$. The sequence $\{m_n\}$ is decreasing and bounded below, so it is convergent and $\lim_{n\to\infty}m_n\ge1/2$. Let's see that the limit is in fact $1/2$.
$$
m_n\le f_n\Bigl(-1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\Bigr)=\frac{1+\Bigl(1-\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}\Bigr)^{2n+1}}{2-\dfrac1{\sqrt{n}}}\to\frac12\text{as }n\to\infty.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

1. $f_n(x)=\frac{x^{2n+1}-1}{x-1}$
2. Find $x \in [-1,0]$ such that $f'(x)=0$

Comment: Just a small note: one should consider $f(-1)$ and $f(0)$ even if the derivative is unequal to zero, as they are the boundary points of the interval.

Comment: About step 2... can't we prove this without using derivation ?